# Azure Functions - ObjectResult renders JSON, but how to configure?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

We have a bunch of web triggered Azure functions. Most of them return an ObjectResult, which is **magically** serialized to Json. However, I cannot find anything in our solution which actually configures this behavior -nor allows to inject some sort of settings object.

What we would like to have is a consistent behavior of serialization and deserialization and limit the coupling of .NET property names with json property names.

Is the only good way to forbid the usage of ObjectResult in favor of some JsonObjectResult? Or is there a way to configure the default serializer?

In StartUp.cs, I have tried to

```
services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(_options => SetDefaultOptions(_options));
services.Configure<JsonSerializerSettings>(_options => SetDefaultOptions(_options));
```

but no callback is happening.

Our projects have a reference to Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.2" which in hand references AspNet.WebApiClient v5.0.4 which then references Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3....so I assume that actually Newtonsoft json is used for serialization

How is it configurable?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in Azure Functions you can include a variable in your program which take care of your serialization and deserialization.

**For serialization**

```cs
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
return new  HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json")
};
```

**For Deserialisation :**

```cs
var response = await client.GetAsync("<url>");
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var o= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<"Type">(json);
```

**[For Customizing serialization and deserialization :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-serialization-and-persistence?tabs=csharp#customizing-serialization-and-deserialization)**
Below are the default settings that uses for Json. Net

**Inputs, Outputs, and State:**

```cs
JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
}
```

Below Example will help in adding Exceptions in your code if required.

```cs
JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new ExceptionResolver(),
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
}
```

For more detailed documentation about `JsonSerializerSettings` you can refer [HERE](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I've just spent days investigating an issue *caused by* the magic serialization that you refer to, and eventually worked out that a change in this magic was the cause. This may not necessarily be an answer to your question, but it is certainly some key information (too big for a comment), and I hope it helps.

If you use the "Azure Functions" project template, and pick the ".NET 6.0 (Long term support)" option (which gives an "in-process" implementation), then it uses Newtonsoft for the serialization, so you need to use Newtonsoft.Json attributes on the objects which are being serialized. For example `[JsonProperty("@odata.type")]`.

If you use the "Azure Functions" project template, and pick the ".NET 6.0 Isolated (Long Term Support)" option (which gives an "isolated" implementation) then it uses System.Text.Json serialization, so for example you would need `[JsonPropertyName("@odata.type")]` from that namespace.

The later versions are all isolated, and I have certainly confirmed that the "8" version follows the same approach as the "6/isolated" version.

However, as demonstrated in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78127370/how-to-test-azure-function-objectresults-json-serialization), there is no obvious way to tell which approach is being used by the code - the code is basically identical, but behaves differently.

If I get an answer to my question, I am hoping to be able to add a unit test to prove that the JSON serialization of the function's response is being done correctly, and it sounds like you would be interested in that too.